# can i restore soft deleted entity in apache atlas?

Tags: apache-atlas

i want restore a soft deleted entity in apache atlas, cause i want to delete the classification tagged on that entity.

i'm using atlas for data governance in HDP cluster. 
And i deleted an entity without deleting the classification tagged on that. 
When i want to delete the classification tagged on that entity, it turns out i can't delete that classification. 
Cause the tagged entity was soft deleted, so atlas thought the classification i want to delete still have references.
So i want to restore the soft deleted entity, i found there are no API support restore in Atlas 7.0, so i try to change the data in related Solr index and Hbase tables. 
I changed the data in Solr index "vertex_index" from "DELETED" TO "ACTIVE', and the data in Hbase table "ATLAS_ENTITY_AUDIT_EVENTS" show the entity status is "ACTIVE". 
But when i search it in Atlas UI, it still shows that the entity is 'DELETED'. 
So, i'm wondering do i miss some thing, can anyone know where exactly atlas store its entity data, and if i can't restore that data, can i delete it in the database or some where else?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly delete the classification associated with the deleted entity. Atlas provides REST API for the same.
"/v2/entity/guid/{guid}/classification/{classificationName}"